# Make a cell editable (after creating the table with non-editable cells) with ctrl+click

Tags: python, pyqt, qtablewidget

I have a QTableWidget that is created when the program starts with non editable and non selectable cells. When I do right click on them the number on the cell increases by 1, which is fine.

What I want to do now is that if I ctrl+click in a cell, this one turns into an editable cell and I can write a number in it, and when the number is entered the cell becomes non editable again.

I have no problem with the modifiers so far and they work, but I can't manage to change the flags of the cell

```
def mousePressEvent(self,event):

    modifiers = event.modifiers()
    it = self.itemAt(event.pos())

    if modifiers & QtCore.Qt.ControlModifier:
          item.setFlags(itemIsEditable)
    else:                        
          if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
              it.setText(str(round(float(it.text())+1)))
          elif event.button() == QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
              it.setText(str(round(float(it.text()) - 1)))
```

Comment: I believe what you want to do is to trigger the editing on the item. If that's correct, you need to call [editItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#editItem) method after setting the flags: `editItem(item)`

Comment: Thanks Dmtry, that's exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `editItem()` method

```
def mousePressEvent(self,event):
    modifiers = event.modifiers()
    it = self.itemAt(event.pos())

    if modifiers & QtCore.Qt.ControlModifier:
          it.setFlags(it.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable)
          self.editItem(it)
    else:            
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
              it.setText(str(round(float(it.text())+1)))
        elif event.button() == QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
              it.setText(str(round(float(it.text()) - 1)))
```

Comment: I didn't know that method! Thanks a lot, it works exactly as I needed!